# Mongo db aggregation with $lookup

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I m trying to build a useful report for a page I m creating, but I m having issues with formatting the data, take a look at this below :

```
db.getCollection('store_spendings').aggregate(
{
  "$project": { "spend_dollars": 1, "comments.text": 1, "comments.user.user_id": 1, "store_id": 1 }
},
{
  "$lookup":
     {
        "from": "corporate_spendings",
        "localField": "store_id",
        "foreignField": "store_id",
        "as": "corporate_spendings"
    }
},
{
  "$match": { "corporate_spendings.region_id": 10816 }  
},
{
  "$project": { "spend_dollars": "$spend_dollars", "comments": 1, "prior_year_spend_dollars": "$corporate_spendings.prior_year_spend_dollars" } }
)
```

I get a result like this :

```
[
  spend_dollars: 321312,
  comments: [...comments data],
  prior_year_spend_dollars: [1231231],
  ...
]
```

I get correct results except the format of data is a bit off for `prior_year_spend_dollars`. I would like it to be a field just like `spend_dollars` rather than an array.

I've tried using `$first` but apparently it only works with group. Right now I do this 'first' operation in my app, but ideally it would be done on the db.

My ideal output with be like this :

```
[
  spend_dollars: 321312,
  comments: [...comments data],
  prior_year_spend_dollars: 1231231,
  ...
]
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Is corporate sendings always an array with size 0 ?

Comment: @Veeram yes it is. It's always one to one mapping

Comment: okay try `prior_year_spend_dollars: {"$arrayElemAt": ["$corporate_spendings.prior_year_spend_dollars", 0]}` in project stage

Comment: @Veeram excellent, can you please post an answer, someone else might find that useful, I wasn't able to find the `$arrayElemAt` function. And I did try to do this for some time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `arrayElemAt` operator in `project` stage which lets you  pick value from array based on index.

```
 "prior_year_spend_dollars": 
{"$arrayElemAt": ["$corporate_spendings.
prior_year_spend_dollars", 0]}
```